# Replace a string inside an environment

Tags: environments

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\testone}{Test one.}
\newenvironment{test}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
    t1
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to replace the string `t1` with `\testone`, but only inside the environment `test`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Are you wanting the string `t1` to be replaced with `\testone` at all locations within the `test` environment?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Why? Just use `\testone` one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most flexible way would be to use regular expressions.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if using LaTeX prior to release 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__blackened_test_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{+b}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__blackened_test_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \,? (\ )? t1 } { \1 \c{testone} } \l__blackened_test_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__blackened_test_tl
 }
 {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\testone}{test one}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
First t1 without a comma.

Then, t1 with a comma.
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

[image: test]

The search regular expression means "a possible comma, followed by a possible space, followed by `t1`; the replacement expression is “if there was a space, reinsert it, then insert `\testone`”.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming Steven B. Segletes' interpretation is correct, you could do something like this.

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\testone}{Test one.}
\NewEnviron{test}{%
\newcommand\patch{\patchcmd{\BODY}{t1}{\testone}{\patch}{}}
\patch\BODY}

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
    t1 abc t1 def
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

The [environ package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) allows us to create environments which 'scoop' their contents into the `\BODY` command. The [etoolbox package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides `\patchcmd`, which is used to replace `t1` with `\testone`. By default, only the first instance is replaced, but the fourth argument of `\patchcmd` is executed on success (and the fifth on failure). This mechanism is used to recursively call the `\patch` command until all instances of `t1` are replaced.

Of course you need to be careful with spaces following instances of `t1`; exactly what you need to do depends on your actual usage case.

Comment: How flexible is it? For example, does it offer the additional capability of disregarding, say, and comma before and after it?

Answer (score 6):

An approach with `listofitems`.  See **SUPPLEMENT** for a version that removes trailing commas (OP had mentioned that in a comment).

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{environ,listofitems}

\newcommand{\testone}{Test one.}
\NewEnviron{test}{%
  \setsepchar{t1}%
  \readlist\myenv{\BODY}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\myenv[]{%
    \z
    \ifnum\zcnt<\listlen\myenv[]\relax\testone\fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
    Here is t1 and t1 again.

    Multi paragraph t1 OK!
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

**SUPPLEMENT**

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{environ,listofitems}

\newcommand{\testone}{Test One}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{test}{%
  \setsepchar{t1/,}%
  \readlist\myenv{\BODY}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\myenv[]{%
    \if\relax\myenv[\zcnt,1]\relax\expandafter\@gobble\z\else\z\fi
    \ifnum\zcnt<\listlen\myenv[]\relax\testone\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
    Here is t1 and t1, again.

    Multi paragraph t1 OK!
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `\StrSubstitute` from the `xtring` pacakge:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\testone}{Test one.}
\NewEnviron{test}{%
    \StrSubstitute{\BODY}{t1}{TEST ONE}%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
    t1 some text t1 and more text.
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

Observe that this approach deletes *one comma* that immediately precedes or follows 't1' inside a 'test' environment. If you would like to delete any number of commas, change the `?` character in the search portion of the `string.gsub` function to `*`. (In Lua's pattern-matchin terminology, `?` denotes "0 or 1" occurrence, while `*` denotes "0 or more" occurrences.)

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% Don't load 'fontenc' and 'inputenc' when using LuaLaTeX
\documentclass {article}    
\newcommand{\testone}{Test one.}
\newenvironment{test}{}{}

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
local in_test_env = false -- initialize a Boolean variable
function replace_t1 ( s )
   if string.find ( s , "\\begin{test}" ) then 
      in_test_env = true  -- switch the Boolean variable to 'true'
   elseif string.find ( s , "\\end{test}" ) then
      in_test_env = false -- switch the Boolean variable to 'false'
   elseif in_test_env == true then -- replace any occurrences of 't1'
      s = string.gsub ( s , "%,?t1%,?" , "\\testone" )
   end
   return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% assign the Lua function to LuaTeX's 'process_input_buffer' callback
\AtBeginDocument{ \directlua { luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
   "process_input_buffer" , replace_t1 , "replacet1" )}}

\begin{document}
t1.

\begin{test}%
,t1,

,,t1,,
\end{test}

t1.
\end{document}
```